# Getting error near div tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am new to react js..

When i run it i am getting syntax near  tag i don't know why.. :(

```
<script type="text/babel">
var movie = react.createClass({
  render:function(){
    return{
    <div>
<h1>{this.props.movietitle}</h1>
<h3>{this.props.moviegenre}</h3>
    </div>
  };
}
});
ReactDOM.render(
<div>

  <movie movietitle="Avatar" moviegenre="Action" />

</div>,document.getElementById('takevalue'));
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried `<movie movietitle="Avatar" moviegenre="Action"></movie>`?

Comment: No still not working and same error on console @connexo

Comment: Please create a fiddle or pen.

Comment: *ReactDOM.render(): Invalid component element. Instead of passing a string like 'div', pass React.createElement('div') or <div />*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should have `()` for wrapping the return. Not the `{}`. And React components must be capitalized(`<Movie/>`)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="takevalue"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
  var Movie = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
      return(
        <div>
          <h1>{this.props.movietitle}</h1>
          <h3>{this.props.moviegenre}</h3>
        </div>
      )
    }
  })
  ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Movie movietitle="Avatar" moviegenre="Action" />
  </div>,document.getElementById('takevalue'));
</script>
```

You need `Babel` to convert jsx into js.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried to create a fiddle from OP's code. It seems to do absolutely nothing, also not producing any console errors or anything. http://codepen.io/connexo/pen/wzLGMg

Comment: Thanx for the help :)

Comment: problem was the var name @connexo